# Reload WebView on Button Press? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, webview

I have a WebView inside my Android Studio project that fills the whole screen, and when they get into the app without an internet connection I show an activity that I have included, I hide the WebView, and I show text and a button telling them they don't have internet. How can I have the button reload the WebView when it is pressed? Reloading the whole app would work as well but as a last resort.

This is my activity-main.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp">

    </WebView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/no_internet_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                layout="@layout/no_internet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is my no-internet.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="Sorry (user)!"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.063"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errorMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:text="Something went wrong with this app."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errorCode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:text="ERROR_INTERNET_DISCONECTED"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/errorMessage"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/refreshButton"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:text="Retry"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.854"
        app:strokeColor="@color/blue_primary" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="237dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is my MainActivity.java file:

```html
package com.example.projectname;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        LinearLayout no_internet_view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.no_internet_view);//////this line for define no_internet_view
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://websitename.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        if (isInternetOn()) {
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            no_internet_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            no_internet_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed(); //maybe shove option first later
        }
    }

    public boolean isInternetOn() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
}
```

My reloadButton will be what should reload the page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using Java. I have made an example for you:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("url");

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reloadButton);
        
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                webview.reload();
                
            }
        });
    }
```

When the button is pressed, the webview reloads.

Comment: I can't do it exactly like that because I get the error of: onCreate(Bundle)' is already defined in 'com.example.projectname.MainActivity'. I do think the code works, but can I have help on how I can add the code to where I don't get this error? Thanks!

Comment: Then only add this code under where you load the webview URL: `Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reloadButton);
        
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                webview.reload();
                
            }
        });`

Answer (score 0):

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
           webview.loadUrl("url");
            
        }
    });
```